# Outlook: Blank lines deleted in archived emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

On *some* of my emails which have been moved to my .pst archive, all of the blank lines have been removed. Even the included text of the previous messages below are modified.

I have not changed any settings and have not found any "space saving" setting which might be doing this. It just started at some point. I can also find no rhyme or reason why it does it for some emails and not for others. It applies to all emails (new, replied, received, forwarded...).

Our IT has suspected my .pst file and has run 2 different repair tools on it. The file is relatively old and is over 10gb in size. The repairs have not helped though. Also my hard drive was recently wiped and windows re-installed, which hasn't helped either.

After an extensive google search I've found nothing. Anyone ever heard of this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable the "Remove extra line breaks..." setting in Outlook Options -> Mail -> Message format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed that's the first thing I checked, but it was not selected and the option has no effect on the behavior whatsovever.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to turn on "Cached Exchange Mode"?

Go in: File -> Account Setting
Select your account and click on "Change"
Check the box "Use Cached Exchange Mode"

I had the same problem and it solved it